# errai GWT data binding getting failed

Tags: gwt, errai

I am trying to run errai databinding in my GWT application

simply followed this tutorial , but with no luck

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Data+Binding

I am kept on getting errors, resolved some by adding some jars etc.

Now , I am getting this error which I am not able to resolve

```
                      [ERROR] Error generating BindableProxyLoaderImpl
                     java.lang.AbstractMethodError:    org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField.getDeclaringClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Here is the screenshot of m console and the Jars i am using

Please guide

http://screencast.com/t/TdECCZNTxc

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar files

Comment: yeah , most probably, but cant get which are the wrong jars , can u please give any idea.

Comment: You should start using Maven or Gradle so you get dependencies right and also there's a errai-tutorial on Github try that first